# gl_DrawID equivalent for Directx12 ExecuteIndirect HLSL

Tags: winapi, hlsl, directx-12

In OpenGL multidraw shaders we use `gl_DrawID` in the glsl shaders and access a array in a Shader Storage Buffer Object (SSBO). In DirectX12 with the advent of ExecuteIndirect I was wondering if there is a similar system variable defined for HLSL?

I know we can change the RootConstant for each draw as part of the indirect buffer structure, but if I wanted the same UAV Buffer or Structured Buffer bound in the root constant for each draw would it would be nice to use an equivalent `gl_DrawID` or is it just not available and I am forced to change root constants per draw?

Comment: There is no equivalent of gl_DrawID in HLSL. You could open an issue in DXC github.